# CSS: set font weight depending on fallback font

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to set the font-weight for an element based on the font that gets chosen. For example, I may be trying to do something like this:

```
h1 {
    font-family: Arial Narrow, Impact, sans-serif;
    font-weight: ?;
}
```

Let's say I want the font-weight to be "bold" if the user has Arial Narrow installed on their system, but "normal" if the browser has to use Impact, and maybe "bold" if the user's system has neither of those fonts. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm 99.99999% sure this can't be done without some serious JavaScript magic, and even with JavaScript it's *damn* difficult to find out which font was used in the end.

Related: [get computed font-family in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960817/get-computed-font-family-in-javascript) asked by yours truly

Comment: Hey! I was going to say that! +1

Comment: I agree with Pekka, I have never seen this before. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945644/is-there-a-way-to-check-what-fonts-are-installed-on-machines-via-the-web

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work? Untested.

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "ArialBold";
    src: local("Arial Narrow");
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "ImpactNormal";
    src: local("Impact");
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "SansSerifBold";
    src: local("sans-serif");
    font-weight: bold;
}
h1 {
    font-family: ArialBold, ImpactNormal, SansSerifBold;
}
</style>
```