# Font Weight with Different Fonts

Tags: css, fonts, google-webfonts

Is it possible to mate a particular font family to a specific font weight?

For instance, if I use Francois One from Google Web Fonts, it seems to look good at font-weight:500. Unfortunately, though, if a web browser never downloads Francois One, or doesn't have the capability to see web fonts, then font-weight:500 means most users won't see a bold font.

I want bold on all browsers, but for those who actually download Francois One, I want them to see font-weight:500.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you import the Google Font via `<link>` in the html document, I think you can specify which weight you import for that particular font:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One:500' type='text/css' />
```

It's about 10 months too late but I stumbled across your question in search of a similar fix and found a closely-related question. I suspect you have found a solution or another method, but just in case: [CSS: set font weight depending on fallback font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647728/css-set-font-weight-depending-on-fallback-font)

Apparently, it can't be done without Javascript intervention, and at that point I think it would be overkill. I hope this finds you some use! I'd be interested if you were able to solve this.