# javascript/css font detection

Tags: javascript, css

here is the code for detecting fonts available to the browser through javascript.

```
   /**
   * Usage: d = new Detector();
    *        d.detect('font name');
   */
   var Detector = function() {
   // a font will be compared against all the three default fonts.
   // and if it doesn't match all 3 then that font is not available.
   var baseFonts = ['monospace', 'sans-serif', 'serif'];

   //we use m or w because these two characters take up the maximum width.
  // And we use a LLi so that the same matching fonts can get separated
  var testString = "mmmmmmmmmmlli";

  //we test using 72px font size, we may use any size. I guess larger the better.
  var testSize = '72px';

  var h = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

  // create a SPAN in the document to get the width of the text we use to test
  var s = document.createElement("span");
  s.style.fontSize = testSize;
  s.innerHTML = testString;
  var defaultWidth = {};
  var defaultHeight = {};
  for (var index in baseFonts) {
    //get the default width for the three base fonts
    s.style.fontFamily = baseFonts[index];
    h.appendChild(s);
    defaultWidth[baseFonts[index]] = s.offsetWidth; //width for the default font
    defaultHeight[baseFonts[index]] = s.offsetHeight; //height for the defualt font
    h.removeChild(s);
  }

  function detect(font) {
    var detected = false;
    for (var index in baseFonts) {
        s.style.fontFamily = font + ',' + baseFonts[index]; 
    // name of the font along with the base font for fallback.
        h.appendChild(s);
        var matched = (s.offsetWidth != defaultWidth[baseFonts[index]]          ||                s.offsetHeight != defaultHeight[baseFonts[index]]);
        h.removeChild(s);
        detected = detected || matched;
    }
    return detected;
  }

   this.detect = detect;
   };
```

if we input any font name here in this code

```
      d = new Detector();
     d.detect('font name');
```

it will return true or false.

But i am finding a way to ouput list of all available fonts instead of boolean value.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. That's why people bother with this kind of detection in the first place - it's the only way

Comment: @Pekka웃 i think its possible.

Comment: You say "all the three default fonts". But there are five.

Comment: It's not possible to get a named list of all available fonts on a client's machine via JavaScript. There seems to be a way with Flash, though. This question is related: [Is there a way to check what fonts are installed on machines via the web?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/945644)

Comment: @Pekka웃 already there is a way to output all available fonts through swf. But this is with only javascript.

Comment: i want output like this  http://hasseg.org/stuff/fontList/example.html

Comment: That example uses Flash (and seems to work well). What makes you think a pure JavaScript solution exists when  all related answers say otherwise?

Comment: @Pekka웃 swf solution is working fine is computers. when it comes to mobiles not working. so a pure javascript solution will help.

Comment: Sure it would be helpful, but as said, it doesn't seem to be possible. What is your situation, why do you need a list of the client's fonts? Maybe there is a different way to do what you need.

Comment: @Pekka웃 its possible. i know this website using javascript solution.  http://fingerprint.pet-portal.eu  working even in mobiles. based on http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect

Comment: That font list is not complete on my machine. My guess is that site is doing exactly the same boolean test that you have above - just against a huge list of fonts *that they know and entered into the script.* It's not the same thing as detecting the actual list of fonts that the user has installed.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes. at least i want same thing what they did.

Comment: You could analyze their script, or build a font list of your own, e.g. using this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces

Comment: Well one possible solution though I would never recommend doing it for anything more than a fun test is brute forcing font names. It definitely isn't a pretty solution or a remotely fast solution but it would work over time. A pre-defined font list is a much better option.