# What fonts are included (i.e. installed by default) with which operating systems?

Tags: css, fonts, compatibility

Is there a decent resource anywhere listing the fonts included with Mac OS X and (post-XP) Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Mac_OS_X

Windows - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_fonts (Includes all windows version, but it notes next to each font which one is for which version(s)

Also, see this for a list of fonts common to both http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Answer (score 5):

The [Complete Guide to Pre-Installed Fonts in Linux, Mac, and Windows](http://www.apaddedcell.com/web-fonts) is a good resource.  I check it before using fonts on web pages to make sure that they'll work for each of these 3 operating systems.

Comment: Nice page, but I'd take the pan-Unicode font list with a grain of salt. Specifying those tends to override the (usually better) script detection of the browser and Arial Unicode MS (e. g.) has enough problems. Also it doesn't really cover Vista and Windows 7, except for the few fonts that are available for XP with an extra download.

Answer (score 0):

See also:

- Stack Overflow: [What are good web development fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003176/what-are-good-web-development-fonts)
- Doctype: [What fonts are included with which operating systems?](http://doctype.com/fonts-included-which-operating-systems)