# Can I embed Arial Narrow in a web page for free using @font-face?

Tags: fonts, font-face

I want to embed Arial Narrow in a website using `font-face`, since I’m not sure how widespread it is.

I would like to know if I need to purchase it from a webshop, or I can do this for free?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: I am not a lawyer.**

I believe Arial Narrow is a variant of Arial, which is [owned by Monotype Imaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial#Proprietary_font).

According to Wikipedia’s description of its licence, you can’t distribute the font, and I imagine using it in `font-face` counts as distribution, so you can’t use it with `font-face` for free.

However, it looks like Monotype offer `font-face` licensing for Arial Narrow. See:

- http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=22
- http://www.fontslive.com/font/arial-narrow-family.aspx

Comment: how well spread is this font? Could I count of it being installed on most OS?

Comment: @Dbugger: I asked a question about [fonts that ship with operating systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013252/what-fonts-are-included-with-which-operating-systems). Beyond that, some people run font surveys. I’m not sure which are more representative of the web, but here are a couple http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-WindowsResults.shtml; http://alicious.com/2009-font-survey-safe-web-fonts/

Answer (score 3):

According to [this webpage](http://3.7designs.co/blog/2008/05/8-fonts-you-probably-dont-use-in-css-but-should/), Arial Narrow is installed on 87.08% of all Windows machines and 91.01% of all Mac machines.

Example usage :

```
font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
```

Comment: You answer isn't a properly constructed sentence; one can't understand what you mean without visiting the link.

Comment: Yes it is difficult to understand, sorry.

Comment: @baldrs Most (or all) linux installations don't have "Arial Narrow" font installed by default.