# Vis.js Network - Use a different font than the 3 available

Tags: vis.js, font-family

I would like to use a different font for the labels in my *network* other than Arial, Verdana or Tahoma, which are the default three available fonts.

How do I do that? I don't even want a very fancy font, just Arial Narrow.

If I replace `'arial'` with `'arial narrow'` in the options of my *network*, the *Arial Narrow* font gets correctly applied on my computer, but does not on my phone (I get some kind of *Time New Roman* instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the font is loaded on your page as Vis Network doesn't ship any fonts and different platforms and sometimes even browsers support different fonts. I suppose your cell phone doesn't have Arial Narrow.

PS: It seems that you have to pay for Arial Narrow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189307/2697214.

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to use a free font that's similar to Arial Narrow in order to avoid any copyright issue. I have also loaded the font like you said using font-face, and now it applies correctly to the page both on my computer and on my phone.