# Seeking font which is identical on Windows & browser

Tags: fonts

Sorry, but I know nothing at all about fonts, so I hope that this doesn't sound too dumb.

I am coding a Windows program which allows users to design HTML pages. The web page as seen in the browser should be identical to what was designed in the Windows program (WYSIWYG).

All users will be running Windows and using MSIE (initially; some may use other browsers or even o/s later). I am not sure that users will accept installing new fonts (unless there is no other way to achieve WYSIWYG).

What should I do?

Comment: There is a lot more to creating an application that renders the same as a web browser than selecting fonts.

Comment: Care to expand on that?  (I am positioning controls with the same co-ords)

Comment: @mawg, you also have to position each glyph, pick colors, perform line and character layout, et al. How do you know what the "same" co-ords for a glyph are? There are many factors that change this (tables, margins, padding, alignment, CSS). This can also change at runtime, watch glyphs as you resize your browser window. Even if you solve this, you have the same issues with non-font graphics.

Comment: Aaargh!!  Methinks I will have to settle for that old standby "what you see is *almost* what you get" (as so many have done before me  :-(


Thanks (+1) for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [web development fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003176/what-are-good-web-development-fonts).

Comment: +! A mine of useful information (which I am still working my way thanks!